# how to declare a variable in django template and change the value of that variable in if condition?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to add a profile image in django template for comments for the post... If profile image is not there in the model then I want to replace with the styled text in place of Image. But I'm getting worried about how to tell the django template that if image exists or not...

```
<div class="comment-author">
{% for image in profile %}
    {% if image.profile|slugify == comment.author %}
        {% with "exist" as img %} <!-- if image exist create img variable -->
        <img src="{{ image.profileImg.url }}" alt="{{ image.profile }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if not img %} <!-- using img variable for checking -->
    <span class="userImg"><b>{{ comment.author|make_list|slice:':2'|join:'' }}</b></span>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %} <!-- closing the with statement -->
```

In the above code I have tried to create a variable img using 'with' but getting error in template... What should I do with this?

Comment: Pasting error to question is always useful.

Comment: @webby I know this will be the error with the 'with statement... I'm getting error to that last line... My main motive is how can i declare the variable before if condition and if 'if' statement executed then change the value.. and then use the same variable if value has changed or not...

Comment: You cannot do this, and you should not try. Rather, you should implement a method on the Profile model which returns the right data. (It's impossible to answer you more fully, because your code has many other issues, like for example calling your profiles "image" and then accessing a "profile" method on that profile.)

Comment: I googled this issue and found some like... create function in views then return the value to the template... but I'm confused, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Template tags are not closing properly.  Please refer to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) Also, improved code a bit.

```
<div class="comment-author">
{% for image in profile %}
    {% if image.profile|slugify == comment.author %}
        {% with "exist" as img %} <!-- if image exist create img variable -->
        <img src="{{ image.profileImg.url }}" alt="{{ image.profile }}">

{% else %} <!-- using img variable for checking -->
    <span class="userImg"><b>{{ comment.author|make_list|slice:':2'|join:'' }}</b></span>
{% endif %}

{% endwith %} <!-- closing the with statement -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I declared the endwith in last line

Comment: you closing your for loop early move it to last line

Comment: With this update all the profilePics will be displayed for the same comment... either image or styled text

Comment: problem could be your if statement condition